# How can I list my github repository and create a new github repository using postman

Tags: javascript, github, postman, web-api-testing

I want to test some endpoints using postman
1. list all of my repositories
2. create repositories
2.delete a repositories
and 4. rename a repositories

Comment: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/

Answer (score 0):

1. For Listing all the repositories - `GET Request on below URL`

`https://api.github.com/users/<user-name>/repos`

2. For Creating Repository - `POST request on below URL`

`https://api.github.com/user/repos`

3. For deleting the Repositories - `DELETE request on below URL`

`https://api.github.com/repos/<:owner>/<:repo>`

For details on what are the arguments required, Please read the official Github API V3 documentation - https://developer.github.com/v3/